# Charuco board with opencv 4.7 in python

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I can't figure out how to generate a charuco board using opencv 4.7. Functions have changed a lot and from what I understand it should now be called like this:

```
dictionary = aruco.Dictionary(aruco.DICT_4X4_50, 4)
board = aruco.CharucoBoard((chkbrd_width, chkbrd_height), 6, 4, dictionary)
image = board.generateImage((1000, 1000), None, 10, 1)
```

But I keep receiving errors such as this on:

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/aruco/aruco_dictionary.cpp:198: error: (-215:Assertion failed) byteList.total() > 0 && byteList.total() >= (unsigned int)markerSize * markerSize / 8 && byteList.total() <= (unsigned int)markerSize * markerSize / 8 + 1 in function 'getBitsFromByteList'`

If I check the dictionary using `dictionary.bytesList`, I receive the following output:

```
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]])
```

This is all very frustrating, the charuco module was working quite well before so I'm not sure what the rational for changing it was.
Thanks.

Comment: first argument to Dictionary is a Mat called `bytesList`, not `DICT_4X4_50`. why did you attempt to pass that named constant to the Dictionary constructor? https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d0b/classcv_1_1aruco_1_1Dictionary.html#a98441378c929f51821b58eeb8be01043

Comment: Ok thanks. I simply misread the documentation. Predefined dictionaries should be obtained with getPredefinedDictionary, which does not belong to the Dictionary class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Christoph's comment, I fixed the code with:

```
aruco_dict = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_4X4_50)
board = aruco.CharucoBoard((11, 7), 20, 15, aruco_dict)
board_image = board.generateImage((1000, 1000), None, 0, 1)

cv2.imshow('charuco', board_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```